# Scaling of ethereum

Tags: transactions, blockchain, scalability

I was trying to find an answer through the internet. What is the problem with ethereum scalling? Found some answers but i dont know which one is correct.

1. It is hard to scale etereum due to the block size, thay want keep block size small so everyone can be full node - [source](https://www.coindesk.com/information/will-ethereum-scale/) i dont why it matter so much, does block which are not filled with transactions still occupy same amount of space?
2. It is due GAS limit per block. I know there is gas limit per block - pi* million and it is not fixed, but because of that usage of all gas give us 15tx per sec
3. It is due to the performance of single core of cpu, but i couldn't find explanation to that.

So my questions is which one is the reason why ethereum cant scalle to 15tx per sec (25tx per sec after optimization)? Maybe it is not on the list.

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect. I suggest you ask the question and edit away your assumptions unless you have source reference for them.

Comment: check devcon3 videos. They talk about it. Here is the agenda where you can find talks about scalability https://ethereumfoundation.org/devcon3/agenda/  and here are the videos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNOfzGXD_C9YMYmnefmPH0g/playlists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with Ethereum, like with most public blockchains, is that every miner has to do everything:

- all miners have to store the history of transactions
- all miners have to validate all transactions sent by anyone
- all miners have to compute everything contained in a transaction.

Since ethereum intends on being a general turing complete platform, the problem is even more exacerbated.

Its like all facebook would run on a single pc, not even a very performant one. Every user interaction would have to go through that server. Just that you have multiple copies of that pc doing the same thing.

Actually since ethereum is supposed to be a platform hosting multiple applications and services, its like the entire internet would  run on a single pc. Now that is kind of a scarry thought in terms of scalability right ?